# How to pass value in method in dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, variable-assignment

What I have is data table and I have method in that returns me list.

Syntax I have is

```
 <h:dataTable id="imageList3" 
  value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.loadReviewReportDataByIdNewFormat()}"
  var="reviewMyList" width="80%" border="1">
```

What I want to do is Pass variable name `#{patentMyList.patentId}` name in method `loadReviewReportDataByIdNewFormat()`. However I am not able to do so....

Any idea how to get this done?

I know if I would had commandButton, I would have used `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

### Note :

if I use, its working

```
 <h:dataTable id="imageList3" 
  value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.loadReviewReportDataByIdNewFormat(1)}"
  var="reviewMyList" width="80%" border="1">
```

However

```
 <h:dataTable id="imageList3" 
  value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.loadReviewReportDataByIdNewFormat(#{patentMyList.patentId})}"
  var="reviewMyList" width="80%" border="1">
```

### Data type of `patentId` is Long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `#{}` activates ExpressionLanguage evaluation, so you can just do:

```
#{yourBean.loadReviewReportDataByIdNewFormat(patentMyList.patentId)}
```

You may be expecting it would be like `$some_variable` like in PHP and other template based languages, but it's not: once activated, you can use the plain variable names and operands.

Check out the [EL info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) for more information.